# UINavigationBar inside of each view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my iOS app I have an UITabBarController. On the top of each view that will be inside the TabBar I want to have a NavigationBar with title. I don't want to use this NavigationBar for navigation between views, I want only to use it for showing a title of a view.

In my opinion it is not good idea to put NavigationBar into each view. This NavigationBar should be in a root view - view of TabBarController. But if I put it into the root view, sub view overlaps root view with NavigationBar which is not visible.

Can you tell me how I should solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my opinion it is not good idea to put NavigationBar into each view.

I don't agree. You can drug Navigation Bar in multiples views, especially if you want different Navigation Bar buttons in each view.

[image: Screenshot from Xcode]
If it's a bad coding practice, Apple wouldn't include the bar without controller in Xcode. For example they do not include hamburger navigation controller because it's bad design idea.

Comment: You are right I guess. It seemed like a better solution to have only one NavigationBar and only change its title. But I will put NavigationBar into each view...

Comment: -1: You can do endless things that don't make sense - that doesn't mean Apple backs every one of them, nor that they are saying not to use hamburger navigation. Using the navigation bar without a navigation controller is *possible*, but you get many things managed for you automatically if you use a navigation controller, like the `navigationItem` on each view controller automatically hooking up the bar to the right configuration. So not using the navigation controller may occasionally be the right choice, but at the cost of having to go back and do it over if you ever need something more.

Answer (score 3):

Embed your ViewController in a `UINavigationController`. By doing this, you will get a navigation Bar in your View Controller and you can set the title there. For embedding, follow these steps.

1. In your `storyboard`, click on the View Controller so that the blue border appears on it.
2. After that, Go to Editor Menu in the Menu Bar and click on Embed In.
3. Click on Navigation Controller.

Here, If currently your View controller is embedded in a `UITabBarController`, then also its fine. Just follow these steps and you will have a navigation Bar as well as the tab bar menu at the bottom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to use NavigationController because I want only show views title. I am not going to use navigation.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the navigation bar:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To show it:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```